# HTTP Basic Authentication for SOAP Web Service Request in VBA

Tags: vba, api, dom, soap

My request is not passing the authentication stage. So I am trying to figure out what is going wrong either in my authentication stage or before.

I know my key and password work because I am able to access the web service using my other code, but in VBA I am not able to.

I think my error is occurring in my request headers, so if you could take a look at them and let me know if you see something wrong or missing.

I know that my "Content-Type" header is suppose to me "text/xml", and that my authentication is suppose to be in the Basic HTTP Authentication form.

I also have my request envelope I just did not include it because it is a lot of code, and not necessary to include for my question. If you do want to see it let me know and I will attach it.

I have attached below the code of where my error is occurring, as well as my function which encodes my credentials to pass, so let me know any tips you may have (Sensitive information was changed to "*****").

```
Sub CreateShip()
    
    Dim request As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim response As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    Dim key As String
    key = "*****"
    Dim pswd As String
    pswd = "*****"
    
     With request
        .Open "Get", "https://devwebservices.purolator.com/EWS/V2/shipping/Shippingservice.wsdl", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncBase64(key & ":" & pswd)
        ' Request Envelope 
        .send
    End with
End Sub

Function EncBase64(strData As String) As String

    Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
    Dim arData() As Byte
    arData = StrConv(strData, vbFromUnicode)
    Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.nodeTypedValue = arData
    EncBase64 = objNode.Text
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing
    'Debug.Print strData
    'Debug.Print EncBase64
    
End Function
```

Comment: "having trouble" is not very descriptive - specifically what happens when you run this code?

Comment: Try `.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncBase64(key & ":" & pswd) `  FYI you should avoid use of `+` for string concatenation in VBA.

Comment: When I run the code it returns a bunch or question marks (?????????????????????????). I also talked to the technicians who manage the API and they said they are not seeing my key in their system which means something is going wrong in my authentication or before. They dud try my key and password in code they know that works and were able to access the API so I know I am using the correct key and password, so I think it is something going wrong with my "opening" of the request.

Comment: I just tried the .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & EncBase64(key & ":" & pswd) and I am still getting the same response of: ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????=???????????????????????????????????????????•??????????????????????????`?????????????????????4??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????8???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????‰‰‰??????8???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: How are you viewing that response?  Looks like you may have a character encoding issue...

Comment: Debug.Print ObjHTTP.responseBody. This is how I am viewing the response

Comment: Have you tried instead writing the response to a worksheet cell?  The Immediate pane will fail to properly display some text encodings...

Comment: Im in access, but I just wrote the response to a text file and got the same response. Could it be something wrong with a library I am using?

Comment: Look at the response headers - they should tell you what the response format/encoding is...  eg `Msgbox ObjHTTP.getAllResponseHeaders()`

Comment: Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Type: text/html
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2023 17:42:05 GMT
Content-Length: 129
Its in html. Is there a different way to display html?

Comment: Have you tried MsgBox?  You're not sending any body content with your POST though?

Comment: I am I just have not included it because it is a lot of code. If you like I could add it. But, like I said before the error is occurring before at the beginning of the request before authorization, because I am not even showing up in there system

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see outputting `.responseText` to a worksheet cell:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">
<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=iso-8859-1""/>
<title>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</title>
<style type=""text/css"">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:""trebuchet MS"", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id=""header""><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id=""content"">
 <div class=""content-container""><fieldset>
  <h2>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</h2>
  <h3>The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The API docs are behind a login, so I'm not able to see those.

Comment: Yea I am seeing the exact same thing when I do ".responseText". Meaning my credentials are not working for some reason, which is not making sense to me why that is happening.

Comment: That's not what the message says though - it's telling you "HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed" - ie POST is not allowed for that endpoint.